# How to group by 2 columns, but have the values on the same row

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Not sure how to exactly explain this in words, but I think with a couple of examples it will make sense

In [this first example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cmv5Y1M5tEkvMW7s?preview), I am grouping by just one column, **location**. In the location fields, I am using spaces in the path, ie `location: ['Home', ''],` (1 space), `location: ['Home', ' '],` (2 spaces) so I can have 2 other columns as "details" of the main row (ie in this example cleaner type and cleaner weight)

It looks like this:

[image]

Perhaps there is a better way to do this, but this would work in the above if I just wanted to group by the one column.

However, I actually want to group by **two** columns, but only have those 2 detail (child) records "nested").

In the above, I also want to group by the **room**, but NOT have room as a nested row.

So, in the above I have `(location=Home, room=room1)`, but I may also have `(location=Home, room=room2)`, ie I have **room2**

eg would like like this:

[image]

I have tried all sorts of things, but just cannot get this view (I always end up with unwanted nestings), eg this is what I **don't** want:

[Plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z024sSIWYEQis1mY)

Is there a way to do this sort of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to do this from [this post](https://ag-grid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017407412-Displaying-duplicated-labels-in-the-tree-Working-with-ID-s-to-specify-the-hierarchy-of-data-but-display-a-label-instead).

So in this example, you can use a completely different property not shown in the grid at all for `getDataPath` to control the grouping, and then use `valueGetter` to put what you want in the grouped column.

So I can have the following....

```
    var gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            // we're using the auto group column by default!
            { field: 'room',resizable: true, },
            { field: 'cleanertype', resizable: true, },    
            { field: 'cleanerweight',aggFunc: 'sum', resizable: true, },
            { field: 'totalweight', resizable: true, },
        ],
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
        },

        autoGroupColumnDef: {
            headerName: 'location',
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
            valueGetter: (params) => {
                return params.node.data.location; // <--- what to show in the group column
            },
            cellRendererParams: {
                suppressCount: true,
            },
        },
        rowData: rowData,
        treeData: true, // enable Tree Data mode
        animateRows: true,
        groupDefaultExpanded: -1, // expand all groups by default
        getDataPath: function (data) {
            return data.grouping;  // <= how to group/nest
        },
    };
```

and the data...

```
        var rowData = [
        // Home/room1
        {
            grouping: ['1'],
            location: 'Home',
            room: 'room1',
            cleanertype: '',    
            totalweight: 60
        },
        {
            grouping: ['1', '1'],    
            cleanertype: 'type1',
            cleanerweight:10,
        },
        {
            grouping: ['1', '2'],    
            cleanertype: 'type2',
            cleanerweight:10,
        },
        // Home/room2
        {
            grouping: ['2'],
            location: 'Home',
            room: 'room2',
            cleanertype: '',    
            totalweight: 60
        },
        {
            grouping: ['2', '1'],   
            cleanertype: 'type1',
            cleanerweight:10,
        },
        {
            grouping: ['2', '2'],    
            cleanertype: 'type2',
            cleanerweight:10,
        },

        {
            grouping: ['3'],
            location: 'Work',
            room: 'room1',
            cleanertype: '',
            cleanerweight: 30,
            totalweight: 60
        },
        {
            grouping: ['3', '1'],               
            cleanertype: 'general',
            cleanerweight:10,
        },

        {
            grouping: ['3', '2'],               
            cleanertype: 'heavyduty',
            cleanerweight: 10,
        },          
    ];
```

So I am using `grouping` to control the grouping/nesting, and works perfectly, and is exactly what I was after.

Can see the working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GgjpmXx2ZHYEEfam).