# How do I use multiple columns for a single group in AG Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

As a toy example, let's say I have 3 columns, "City", "Population", and "Neighborhoods".

Ideally, I want the data to be laid out like this in three columns AG Grid:

```
> San Francisco | 800,000 | Bernal Heights 
                          | The Mission  
                          | ...
> New York      | 8.5 mil | West Village 
                          | Bed Stuy
```

Since population and the city name are 1:1, they should be on the same row, whereas AG Grid defaults to something like this:

```
> San Francisco 
    > 800,000
```

Expanding or collapsing the group should expand / collapse the list of neighborhoods.

Note that in our real use case, each neighborhood would have multiple columns associated with it.

Is there a way to accomplish this in AG Grid (React)?

We saw [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462823/how-to-group-by-2-columns-but-have-the-values-on-the-same-row), but the example given seems very hacky and not super robust.